# Required Field Validator for login page in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm working on the login in one of my asp.net project.

I have completed the login page but facing problem when I have included asp.net validation.

I have inserted required field validator for the username and password textbox in my login page,I have link for new user registration and also forget password.

My problem is, eventhough I want to click new user or forget password link, required field validator for textbox and username shows error message.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use **ValidationGroup** Property to fix this.

ex:

```
 <asp:textbox id="tb1" runat=Server />
<asp:requiredfieldvalidator id="ReqField1" controltovalidate="tb1"
validationgroup="valGroup1" errormessage="Required" runat=Server />

<asp:ImageButton id="Button2" causesvalidation=true
validationgroup="valGroup2" ImageUrl="img.gif" runat=Server />
```

Or Else

Assign **CauseValidation="False"** in New registration and Forget Password Button to fix

Answer (score 2):

Add CausesValidation="false" to the links that should not trigger validation.

Answer (score 1):

change the validation group of these two linkbuttons (forget password, New user linkbuttons) to be not the same of the login button control and I hope your problem will be solved :)..